# Excluir linhas totalizadoras

Tags: r

Eu tenho a seguinte estrutura de um banco de dados:

```
MES EST.DET1 EST.DET2 EST.DET3 DIAS
2  Curso 1  Turma A    Manha    5
2  Curso 1  Turma A    Tarde    5
2  Curso 1  Turma B     <NA>    5
2  Curso 1     <NA>     <NA>   15
2  Curso 2  Turma A     <NA>    7
2  Curso 2     <NA>     <NA>    7
2  Curso 3     <NA>     <NA>   10
3  Curso 1  Turma A    Manha    6
3  Curso 1  Turma A    Tarde    6
3  Curso 1  Turma B     <NA>    6
3  Curso 1     <NA>     <NA>   18
3  Curso 2  Turma A     <NA>    7
3  Curso 2     <NA>     <NA>    7
3  Curso 3     <NA>     <NA>   13
4  Curso 1  Turma A    Manha    5
4  Curso 1  Turma A    Tarde    5
4  Curso 1  Turma B     <NA>    5
4  Curso 1     <NA>     <NA>   15
4  Curso 2  Turma A     <NA>    6
4  Curso 2     <NA>     <NA>    6
4  Curso 3     <NA>     <NA>   10
```

Basicamente, são 3 cursos que ocorrem ao longo de três meses, sendo que os cursos 1 e 2 estruturas "filhas". O curso 1, possui 2 turmas (A e B), sendo que a A pode acontecer de manhã ou a tarde. O curso 2 possui apenas a turma A e o curso 3 não tem estruturas "filhas" detalhadas.

A 4ª linha e as respectivas do Curso 1 para os outros meses, nada mais é do que o totalizador (soma) das estruturas "filhas". O mesmo vale para a 6ª linha (Curso 2).

Existe alguma forma de filtrar meu banco de dados para que essas linhas totalizadoras sejam excluídas? (Vale ressaltar que o Curso 3 deverá ser mantido)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A forma mais simples é utilizar um vetor lógico para selecionar suas linhas:

```
data <- c("2", "Curso 1", "Turma A", "Manha", "5",
          "2", "Curso 1", "Turma A", "Tarde", "5",
          "2", "Curso 1", "Turma B", "",      "5",
          "2", "Curso 1", "",        "",      "15",
          "2", "Curso 2", "Turma A", "",      "7",
          "2", "Curso 2", "",        "",      "7",
          "2", "Curso 3", "",        "",      "10",
          "3", "Curso 1", "Turma A", "Manha", "6",
          "3", "Curso 1", "Turma A", "Tarde", "6",
          "3", "Curso 1", "Turma B", "",      "6",
          "3", "Curso 1", "",        "",      "18",
          "3", "Curso 2", "Turma A", "",      "7",
          "3", "Curso 2", "",        "",      "7",
          "3", "Curso 3", "",        "",      "13",
          "4", "Curso 1", "Turma A", "Manha", "5",
          "4", "Curso 1", "Turma A", "Tarde", "5",
          "4", "Curso 1", "Turma B", "",      "5",
          "4", "Curso 1", "",        "",      "15",
          "4", "Curso 2", "Turma A", "",      "6",
          "4", "Curso 2", "",        "",      "6",
          "4", "Curso 3", "",        "",      "10")

data <- data.frame(matrix(data, ncol = 5, byrow = TRUE))

names(data) <- c("MES", "EST.DET1", "EST.DET2", "EST.DET3", "DIAS")
```

Na execução abaixo, seleciono as linhas que não estejam vazias na coluna 3 ou que contenha 'Curso 3' na coluna 2.

```
data[data[,3] != '' | data[,2] == 'Curso 3', ]
```

Resultado:

```
   MES EST.DET1 EST.DET2 EST.DET3 DIAS
1    2  Curso 1  Turma A    Manha    5
2    2  Curso 1  Turma A    Tarde    5
3    2  Curso 1  Turma B             5
5    2  Curso 2  Turma A             7
7    2  Curso 3                     10
8    3  Curso 1  Turma A    Manha    6
9    3  Curso 1  Turma A    Tarde    6
10   3  Curso 1  Turma B             6
12   3  Curso 2  Turma A             7
14   3  Curso 3                     13
15   4  Curso 1  Turma A    Manha    5
16   4  Curso 1  Turma A    Tarde    5
17   4  Curso 1  Turma B             5
19   4  Curso 2  Turma A             6
21   4  Curso 3                     10
```

Comment: Eu  pensei numa solução dessa forma, mas como tenho muitas variações, estava procurando algo mais automático.

Comment: @RafaelCunha se colocar seu problema com múltiplas variáveis, posso tentar resolver de outra forma.